# How to display all variables in memory with the debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

So this is something I could not find when searching online, the MSDN is pretty hard to navigate through, and I dont really know how to word what I am looking for in the first place.  If this answer is elsewhere and someone can direct me I would appreciate that and delete this question accordingly.

So I have a template class derived from vector.  The class uses two templates, one of which is a primitive and the second is a template struct that uses the primitive as its template argument.  My question is that when I turn on the debugger neither local nor auto or any of the other tabs show the members inside the struct, which are sitting inside the vectors data member.  Is there a way to make those pieces of information visible?  I cant just mouse over things because the vector class has different index points and I want to be able to read the members at every index point.  Is Visual Studio just not capable of this kind of advanced debugging capabilities?  Any answers would be appreciated.

Also this is a code visual of the data members I am trying to access in the debugger:

```
template <class T>
struct qElem
{
    T Data;
    int Priority;
    qElem(T data, int priority) :Data(data), Priority(priority){};
};

template <class T, class T2>
class PriQueue : public vector<T2>
```

*NOTE* I am trying to see what is inside qElem.Data and qElem.Priority inside all indexed instances of PriQueue[index], including all currently made types of PriQueue.

My code works btw, I just am wondering if the debugger is capable of giving this information as I continue to add new functionality to it for the purpose of squashing bugs.

Comment: Still uncertain how to solve this.  I figured out that the watch tab allows you to view information from just about anywhere, but I still have no clue how to access the data members of a struct that are inside the data member of a vector.

Comment: You linking with debug versions of the libs, boost etc?

Comment: I have no clue, which I would assume then means no.  I am simply using debug->start with debugger in VS 2013